# Change button_to attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Im new to ruby on rails and im currently working on a button that will change the attribute depends on the functions result. as of now i create this function that returns true or false.

```
def link_facebook
    is_linked = FacebookLinked.link(env["omniauth.auth"])
    redirect_to :controller => 'dashboard', :action => 'settings'
end
```

i want to change my button_to attribute(Value,class, and make it disable)
if the result retuns true.

```
<%= button_to 'Setup Facebook','/auth/facebook',:class=>'btn btn-default',:id=>'setup_facebook'%>
```

i've search ajax but i have no clue on how to start using it.

Answer (score 0):

If the function that returns a boolean is called `my_function`, the default class (when true) is `'btn btn-default'` and the class when the boolean is false is `'btn btn-default disabled'` then you could use :

```
"btn btn-default #{(my_function ? '': 'disabled')}"
```

So overall :

```
<%= button_to 'Setup Facebook','/auth/facebook',:class=>"btn btn-default #{(my_function ? '': 'disabled')}",:id=>'setup_facebook'%>
```

Please note that you might need to use a helper to call the method from the view, as follows : `helper_method :my function`. Alternatively, you could create the variable in the controller (no need for helper) and pass the variable to the view.

Comment: Be aware `"string" + nil` raise an exception.

Comment: `"btn btn-default #{my_function? '': 'disabled'}"` It's the Ruby, use interpolation.

Comment: No, what i want to do is, change the button's attribute in my controller. because a function inside my controller will check for a model that will return true or false , then if it is true the button will be disabled and changes it's value

Comment: @JohnGeliberte Then the part you're interested in is the last sentence, no ? "Alternatively, you could create the variable in the controller (no need for helper) and pass the variable to the view."

Answer (score 0):

#### Method 1

You can do something like this

```
redirect_to controller: 'dashboard', action: 'settings', is_linked: is_linked
```

Now is linked value will passed to the settings page's url

```
http://localhost:3000/dashboard/settings?is_linked=true
```

In your view

```
<%= button_to 'Setup Facebook','/auth/facebook',:class=>"btn btn-default #{params[:is_linked]? '': 'disabled'}",:id=>'setup_facebook'%>
```

#### Method 2

You can have an instance variable inside your `settings` action in rails, Like this

```
def settings
  @is_linked = FacebookLinked.link(env["omniauth.auth"])
  ...
end
```

So you can access in your view in a similar fashion

```
<%= button_to 'Setup Facebook','/auth/facebook',:class=>"btn btn-default #{@is_linked? '': 'disabled'}",:id=>'setup_facebook'%>
```

Comment: Is the method 1 XSS vulnerable? http://matthewdfuller.com/websectut/xss/main_passing_url.php

Comment: No, I don't think. But a user can change it to `false` in the url and the button can be enabled. But you can't pass params as `post` in a `redirect_to`.

Comment: @Зелёный I saw your link. In our case we're not sending anything to the server. Rather we're getting a parameter from server in our url. In this particular case its harmless.

Comment: I just guess, you sent to the server params in the url `is_linked=true` and server is render it `params[:is_linked]?`, so I can sent something like this `is_linked=<script>alert('hello');</script>` and server should render it. It's just an assumption.